# Residue of $f(z)$ using Laurent Series at $z=-2$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, special-functions

Calculate the residue of:

$$f(z) = \frac{\psi(-z)}{(z+1)(z+2)^3} \space \text{at} \space z=-2$$

Where $\psi(z)$ is the digamma function, and $\zeta(z)$ is the Riemann-zeta function (below).

**The answer given is:** $\displaystyle \mathrm{Res}_{z=-2} f(z) = \frac{\pi^2}{6} +\zeta(3) - 3 +\gamma$

Using the Laurent Series. **Obviously we must find,** the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z+2}$ in  the series expansion.

Using the series definition of $\psi(-z)$ zeta definition

$$\psi(-z)
= 1-\gamma + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (1-\zeta(k+1)) (z+2)^k$$

Or

$$\psi(-z) = -\gamma + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z + 1}{(n+1)(z-n)}$$

How can I approach this?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it'd be a good idea to define $\;\psi (z)\,,\,\,\zeta(z), etc.\;$ . Not all may have seen/remember Riemann's zeta function, gamma and digamma function, etc.